# Apache Solr filtering not working but possible to retrieve by id

Tags: java, solr, solrcloud

**Background:**
We have a 3-node solr cloud that was migrated to docker. It works as expected, however, for new data that is inserted, it can only be retrieved by id. Once we try to use filters, it doesn't show. Note that old data can still be filtered without any issues.

The database is is used via spring-boot crud-like application.

**More background:**

The app and the solr were migrated by another person and I have inherited the codebase recently so I am not familiar in much detail about the implementation and am still digging and debugging.
The  nodes were migrated as-is (the data was copied into a docker mount).

**What I have so far:**

I have checked the logs of all the solr nodes and see the following happening when making the calls to the application:

**Filtering:**

```
2019-02-22 14:17:07.525 INFO  (qtp15xxxxx-15) [c:content_api s:shard1 r:core_node1 x:content_api_shard1_replica0] o.a.s.c.S.Request
[content_api_shard1_replica0]  
webapp=/solr path=/select 
params=
{q=*:*&start=0&fq=id-lws-ttf:127103&fq=active-boo-ttf:(true)&fq=(publish-date-tda-ttf:[*+TO+2019-02-22T15:17:07Z]+OR+(*:*+NOT+publish-date-tda-ttf:[*+TO+*]))AND+(expiration-date-tda-ttf:[2019-02-22T15:17:07Z+TO+*]+OR+(*:*+NOT+expiration-date-tda-ttf:[*+TO+*]))&sort=create-date-tda-ttf+desc&rows=10&wt=javabin&version=2} 
hits=0 status=0 QTime=37
```

**Get by ID:**

```
2019-02-22 14:16:56.441 INFO  (qtp15xxxxxx-16) [c:content_api s:shard1 r:core_node1 x:content_api_shard1_replica0] o.a.s.c.S.Request
[content_api_shard1_replica0]  
webapp=/solr path=/get params={ids=https://example.com/app/contents/127103/middle-east&wt=javabin&version=2} 
status=0 QTime=0
```

**Disclaimer:**

I am an absolute beginner in working with Solr and am going through documentation ATM in order to get better insight into the nuts and bolts.

**Assumptions and WIP:**

- The person who migrated it told me that only the data was copied, not the configuration. I have acquired the old config files (`/opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/`) and am trying to compare to the new ones. But the assumption is that the configs were defaults.
- The old version was `6.4.2` and the new one is `6.6.5` (not sure that this could be the issue)

Is there something obvious that we are missing here? What is superconfusing is the fact that the data can be retrieved by id AND that the OLD data can be filtered

**Update:**

- After some researching, I have to say that I have excluded the config issue because when I inspect the configuration from the admin UI, I see the correct configuration.
- **Also, another weird behavior is that the data can be queried after some time** (like more than 5 days). I can see that because I run the query from the UI and order it by descending creation date. From there, I can see my tests that I was not just days ago

**Relevant commit config part:**

```
 <autoCommit> 
   <maxTime>${solr.autoCommit.maxTime:15000}</maxTime> 
   <openSearcher>false</openSearcher> 
 </autoCommit>

 <autoSoftCommit> 
   <maxTime>${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime:-1}</maxTime> 
 </autoSoftCommit>
```

More config output from the admin endpoint:

```
config:{  
   znodeVersion:0,
   luceneMatchVersion:"org.apache.lucene.util.Version:6.0.1",
   updateHandler:{  
      indexWriter:{  
         closeWaitsForMerges:true
      },
      commitWithin:{  
         softCommit:true
      },
      autoCommit:{  
         maxDocs:-1,
         maxTime:15000,
         openSearcher:false
      },
      autoSoftCommit:{  
         maxDocs:-1,
         maxTime:-1
      }
   },
   query:{  
      useFilterForSortedQuery:false,
      queryResultWindowSize:20,
      queryResultMaxDocsCached:200,
      enableLazyFieldLoading:true,
      maxBooleanClauses:1024,
      filterCache:{  
         autowarmCount:"0",
         size:"512",
         initialSize:"512",
         class:"solr.FastLRUCache",
         name:"filterCache"
      },
      queryResultCache:{  
         autowarmCount:"0",
         size:"512",
         initialSize:"512",
         class:"solr.LRUCache",
         name:"queryResultCache"
      },
      documentCache:{  
         autowarmCount:"0",
         size:"512",
         initialSize:"512",
         class:"solr.LRUCache",
         name:"documentCache"
      },
:{  
         size:"10000",
         showItems:"-1",
         initialSize:"10",
         name:"fieldValueCache"
      }
   },
...
```

Comment: Initial guess - since you're missing the configuration, the new instance is adding the values as string fields and not as their proper types. Since you're filtering by date type, that probably won't work properly with the string field type. A possible issue is that you now have data of different types in your index for the same field, so you might have to be prepared to rebuild your index after making the configuration work properly.

Comment: @MatsLindh, thanks. Where should I look specifically for the data type configuration?

Comment: If you've been running in cloud mode (which it seems like if you had three nodes), the config has been stored in Zookeeper. It can be downloaded using zkCli.sh and downconfig, then uploaded using the upconfig command on the new cluster.

Comment: I have updated the question on the current status and I think I can exclude configuration issues because I see my config inside zookeeper. Yet I am more confused as the data seems to be created after a while

Comment: Are you actually _committing_ your data? i.e. are you issuing a commit after adding data? The real time get endpoint (i.e. /get) allows retrieval of content without a commit being issued, while data won't be searchable before a new commit is issued and a searcher is reopened.

Comment: Well, in the `solrconfig.xml`, I see the default value for the commit (15000 ms) with the `openSearcher` set to false. AFAIK, nothing is changed there

Comment: If opensearcher is false, no changes will be visible until a new searcher is opened.

Comment: I have updated the relevant configuration for `commit` and `soft commit`. Because AFAIK, the soft commit should make the data searchable in that case, shouldn't it?

Comment: Not unless a new searcher is opened (and your example with softcommit is set to `-1`, so no automagic soft commits are done). Changes to your index does not become visible before a new searcher is opened - the old searcher will still work with the index state as it was before you added the new documents. It's usually a good idea to drop configuring this in `solrconfig.xml` and instead use `commitWithin` when indexing documents (and be sure to open a new searcher if you expect the data to be visible as soon as it's committed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your examples you're only retrieving the document when you're querying the realtime get endpoint - i.e. `/get`. This endpoint returns documents by querying by id, even if the document hasn't been commited to the index or a new searcher has been opened.

A new searcher has to be created before any changes to the index become visible to the regular search endpoints, since the old searcher will still use the old index files for searching. If a new searcher isn't created, the stale content will still be returned. This matches the behaviour you're seeing, where you're not opening any new searchers, and content becomes visible when the searcher is recycled for other reasons (possibly because of restarts/another explicit commit/merges/optimizes/etc.).

Your example configuration shows that the autoSoftCommit is disabled, while the regular autoCommit is set to not open a new searcher (and thus, no new content is shown). I usually recommend disabling this feature and instead relying on using `commitWithin` in the URL as it allows greater configurability for different types of data, and allows you to ask for a new searcher to be opened within at least x seconds since data has been added. The default behaviour for commitWithin is that a new searcher will be opened after the commit has happened.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I actually have the `commitWithin` set to true.
I have updated more of the config I get when calling the admin endpoint for getting the configuration of my collection.
Thanks

Comment: `commitWithin` is not a setting - the setting is just saying that _when you issue a commitWithin_ it should be a soft commit. You'll have to include the `commitWithin=<number of milliseconds>` clause in the URL when submitting data to the `/update` endpoint.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it appears that it was that particular config issue. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might have switched to a default managed schema on upgrade. Look for schema.xml in your previous install along with a  section in your prior install's solrconfig.xml. More info at https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-factory-definition-in-solrconfig.html#SchemaFactoryDefinitioninSolrConfig-SolrUsesManagedSchemabyDefault

Comment: Inside the `/configsets` directory I only have `solrconfig.xml` and have compared them but other than the version, they are identical. Where would this `schema.xml` be located?